# How upload Image as element of class?

Tags: php, laravel

I have class `Image`(table, model, controller).
I have fucntion for upload image on server:

```
public function upload(UploadImageRequest $request)
{
    $data = $request->input('image');
    $photo = time().'_'.$request->file('image')->getClientOriginalName();;
    $destination = base_path() . '/public/images';
    $request->file('image')->move($destination, $photo);
    $data['image'] = $photo;
    $path = $data;
}
```

How add upladed image as element of class `Image` and transfer field's: path and url?

Comment: Please share full code and error what you are getting.

Comment: _I have class Image..._ Where is the code of your class?